# UIControl: Touch Up Inside work but Touch Up Outside does not

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have an UIView that in front of a bigger UIView, I want to hide that current View when tap on the behind View but I can't get Touch Up Outside event work, Touch Up Inside that View work fine.

(The behind View have another controls)

Thanks

Tung Do

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Touch Up Outside is triggered when the view is touched, but then the finger moved outside the view and is lifted. You cannot get touch events for other views with that.

To accomplish what you want, you need a transparent view (opaque = NO, backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]) that fills the whole screen behind your view of interest. And for that you can catch the Touch Up Inside event and then hide both views.

Comment: @DarkDust - did u try the solution you are proposing here? If the view is fully transparent or its background color is set to [UIColor clearColor] i wasn't able to pick-up any touch event. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the past by creating a custom UIView and then overriding the pointInside method of the UIView class.  That is the method that will fire every time a UIView gets a touch notification.  When that happens you can then find out whether or not the touch was inside or outside of your views bounds.

For example your custom UIView could look like this:

**CustomTouchUIView.h**

```
#import 

@protocol CustomTouchUIViewDelegate

- (void) uiViewTouched:(BOOL)wasInside;

@end

@interface CustomTouchUIView : UIView 

// Properties
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

@end
```

**CustomTouchUIView.m**

```
#import "TOTouchUIView.h"

@implementation CustomTouchUIView

#pragma mark - Synthesize
@synthesize delegate;

#pragma mark - Touches
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if( point.x > 0 && point.x < self.frame.size.width && point.y > 0 && point.y < self.frame.size.height )
    {
        [delegate uiViewTouched:YES ];
        return YES;
    }

    [delegate uiViewTouched:NO ];
    return NO;
}
@end
```

I have a downloadable example / tutorial online [here](http://kellenstyler.com/index.php/2011/09/20/adding-touchoutside-functionality-to-a-uiview-in-ios/)